# Using cocoaPods for google AdMob SDK

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods

Today I was trying to update GoogleAdMob SDK to 6.12, So while reading documentation I found that google recommends to use **cocoaPods to manage dependencies**.I deleted by previous 6.10 SDK files from my project and did as below.

So I installed cocoaPods on my machine, and followed the steps given in the adMob docs

After installing the pod, I got this message from terminal

```
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (6.12.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `abc.xcworkspace`.

[!] The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:

    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


[!] The `abc [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `abc [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

My first doubt 
**What does these warning means and how to resolve this?**

Secondly

I opened abc.xcworkspace as suggested by cocoaPods, I could see two projects now as screen shot below

[image]

**Here in the image you can see all frameworks are in red. So is that an issue or its fine?**

Lastly my code which was working before using cocoaPods

```
m_googleAdView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 918.0, kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width,kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height);
[m_googleAdView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

**My code for adding bannerView is already coded, But I get these errors now**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[AllViewController viewDidLoad] in AllViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AllViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PageViewController.o     
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AllViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PageViewController.o      
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to add:

```
$(inherited)
```

to `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in your projects build settings tab

[image]

Comment: Ok. I will do it.what about other issues?

Comment: Other errors are linker errors because you didn't added libraries to linker flags. Once you've added $(inherited) it should build

Comment: Ok. I will try it and get back to you

Comment: Is this supposed to remove the warnings when running `pod install` again?

Comment: yes, but $(inherited) should be added as a first line in settings

Comment: That fix me + Have "Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only " with the same value on both project (target and Pods).

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative you can do this:

```
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Go to your project, over **Other Linker flags** (@Andrei's picture above) and press delete. It will delete your settings a write the inherited ones from the pods build settings.

Do not do this if you have additional flags...

@Ranjit: For this issue:

```
[!] The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:
```

Just add this line

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

At the top of your podfile, as it says ...